# Using HTML divs like form

Tags: html, css, forms, bulma

I'm making a website that allows you to upload a picture, name it and then on submit it gives the data to [PHP code](https://codeberg.org/mikolajlubiak/emoteupld/src/branch/master/upload.php).
As of now I'm using just plain HTML and PHP, but I want to add Bulma CSS library.

[Right now the HTML code looks like this:](https://codeberg.org/mikolajlubiak/emoteupld/src/branch/master/index.html)

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="emote" id="emote">
    <br>
    Emote name:
    <input type ="text" name="emotename" id="emotename">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Emote" name="submit">
</form>
```

But the library requires that I use `div`s instead of `form`. The code would look something like:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="field">
        <label class="label">Emote name</label>
        <div class="control">
            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Emote name..." id="emotename">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="file">
        <label class="file-label">
            <input class="file-input" type="file" name="resume" id="emote">
            <span class="file-cta">
                <span class="file-icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
                </span>
                <span class="file-label">
                    Choose a file...
                </span>
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="field is-grouped">
        <div class="control">
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
        <div class="control">
            <button class="button is-link is-light">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I click `Submit` PHP errors: "You need to fill all the fields."

Comment: Just wrap the divs inside the same `<form` tag??

Comment: `I also don't know what is the id tag equivalent in those divs`...it's not clear what you mean, or what problem you're having. All HTML elements can have an `id`

Comment: You have to use javascript to deal with server in ajax for example

Comment: @svgta that shouldn't be necessary. forms don't really interfere with CSS (they have no default style), so the OP should just be able to put a form tag around whatever divs they need in order to work with this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working `form` looks like this:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="field">
        <label class="label">Emote name</label>
        <div class="control">
            <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="Emote name..." name="emotename" id="emotename">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="file">
        <label class="file-label">
            <input class="file-input" type="file" name="emote" id="emote">
            <span class="file-cta">
                <span class="file-icon">
                    <i class="fas fa-upload"></i>
                </span>
                <span class="file-label">
                    Choose a file...
                </span>
            </span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="field is-grouped">
        <div class="control">
            <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>
        <div class="control">
            <button class="button is-link is-light">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).